# Not getting source IP from ingress controller

Tags: nginx, amazon-elb, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

We have setup EKS cluster to deploy application. Flow of traffic is Nginx->LB->IngressController->Application. Where nginx is L7 proxy. We have setup below parameter to forward source IP in headers.

```
location ~* /example/version/test {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://second.example.com;
    }
```

Request is getting forwarded to AWS CLB which we have setup along with ingress controller. In ingress controller configmap we have added these parameter to extract source IP from X-Forwarded-For/X-Real-IP.

```
proxy-real-ip-cidr: <VPC CIDR>
use-forward-headers: "true"
```

When request reaches to pod it is showing EKS node IP address in X-Real-IP and X-Forwarded-For header. I added one more custom header "ip-test" to test out forwarded header like below.

```
location ~* /example/version/test {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header 'ip-test' $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://second.example.com;
    }
```

Surprisingly this header is showing actual source IP but X-forwarded-For and X-Real-IP shows node IP only. I read article where many people suggested to add **externalTrafficPolicy: Local** but didn't work in our case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ingress controller nginx.conf was setting up the `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;` directive as well. I added below annotation in ingress and it worked.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
      real_ip_recursive on;
      set_real_ip_from <VPC CIDR>;
      set_real_ip_from <PROXY IP>;
```